# Feet to meter ( vise versa ) conversion in Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When the user enters value in feet, the application should calculate the meter equivalent and
display the same in meter textfield.

`Formula : 1ft = 0.3048m`

When the user enters a value in the meter, the application should calculate the feet equivalent and display the same in feet text field.

`Formula : 1m = 3.2808ft`

Need to update both values simultaneously when I enter either of the input fields.

[image: sample output]

Here is my code:

```js
function LengthConverter(val) {
  var input2 = document.getElementById("meter").innerHTML = val / 3.2808;
  console.log(input2);
  val.value = input2.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='ftm'>
    <label for="feet">Feet:</label><br>
    <input id="feet" type="number" placeholder="Feet" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
  </div>
  <div class='ftm'>
    <label for="meter">Meter:</label><br>
    <input id="meter" type="number" placeholder="Meters">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you have everything you need, where are you stuck?

Comment: @DBS problem is that I'm not able to update the value in another input feel. But to check the value I did console.log the value is present there. but not outputting to another input field. 

pasted my code in the question.

Comment: What is your current js code?

Comment: Add an onchange event that grabs the neighbouring input fields and makes the changes.

Comment: can you show me some changes by code, please?

Comment: @Scrapper142 you can check above.

Comment: @vazenfino try document.getElementById("meter").value  instead of innerHTML

Comment: @ShreekeshMurkar Not working

Comment: @vazenfino : I have added answer below. It is working. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```js
function LengthConverter(val) {
  var input2 = document.getElementById("meter").value = val / 3.2808;
  console.log(input2);
  val.value = input2.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='ftm'>
    <label for="feet">Feet:</label><br>
    <input id="feet" type="number" placeholder="Feet" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
  </div>
  <div class='ftm'>
    <label for="meter">Meter:</label><br>
    <input id="meter" type="number" placeholder="Meters">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Shreekesh, I got it and I implemented one more function for converting meters to feet. When you commented for the first time I guess it should be working that time it's my mistake that I put an input focus on the text box so that when I type a number in feet it doesn't show in the meters because I haven't focused it yet :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `element.addEventListener` to watch for changes to the elements, then run a function to update the other one

```js
const feetInput = document.getElementById('feet');
const meterInput = document.getElementById('meter');

function updateMeter() {
  meterInput.value = feetInput.value / 3.2808;
}

function updateFeet() {
  feetInput.value = meterInput.value * 3.2808;
}

// an input event is similar to change but only fires when the actual
// contents of the input field change
feetInput.addEventListener('input', updateMeter);
meterInput.addEventListener('input', updateFeet);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='ftm'>
    <label for="feet">Feet:</label><br>
    <input id="feet" type="number" placeholder="Feet">
  </div>
  <div class='ftm'>
    <label for="meter">Meter:</label><br>
    <input id="meter" type="number" placeholder="Meters">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you show what to change in HTML when I use this addEventListener?

Comment: You can mention that `input` results in immediate update since it doesn't wait for the element to lose focus to trigger as `change` does.